# Programming style - Anything wrong with :remote & .js.erb being the main approach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, coding-style

For some 'minor' actions in my site, I'm using `remote` instead of standard HTML requests. My current `remote` technique is like this:

1. Use `form_for` or `form_tag` with `:remote => true`.
2. In the controller action, do:

   ```
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
   end
   ```
3. Then create a `.js.erb` file that loads a partial / creates a flash message / highlights parts of the page, etc.

I want to understand the implications of my approach because I don't want my own ignorance to lead to problems I don't know about.

1. Are there any accessibility problems with the above, i.e. are there people who wouldn't be able to use my code above due to their browser / disability / something else?
2. Is the above the 'current' way to do things in Rails, or can you point me to something that is better?
3. Are there any issues with security or performance that could be improved by doing it another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It doesn't lead to more browser issues than usual js
2. I'd say it's the current way for low traffic or few actions (like admin reserved area)
3. Using this technique leads to more server work than basic ajax returning json handled fully client-side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @apneadiving. Could you clarify: for #2 what is the current way for higher traffic areas? For #3, by client-side ajax are you referring to http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/?

Comment: #2 write js in .js files you include in your views #3 Unobstrusive JS, presented in the article, results in full client side js BUT you've almost to handle the result using rsj which is not that great